# Alamofire Post Request is not Executed

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm making a POST Request to my API. All of a sudden the request is being skipped. I have tried to debug into it, but until now without success.

This is my request:

```
@IBAction func checkLogin(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let managedContext = self.managedObjectContext else { return }

    let user = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: User.identifier, into: managedContext) as! User

    let url = ""

    let parameters: Parameters =
        ["username" : usernameTextField.text!, "password" : passwordTextField.text!]


     Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in

        let results = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
        print(results)

        user.firstName = results["firstname"].string!

        let responseString : String = responseData.response?.allHeaderFields["Set-Cookie"] as! String

        if let range = responseString.range(of: ";"){
            let startIndex = (responseString.range(of: "="))

            let cookie = responseString[(startIndex?.upperBound)!...range.lowerBound]
            user.setValue(cookie, forKey: "token")

        }
    }  do {
        try self.dataController.saveContext()
    }catch {
        print("Save Error User")
    }
```

I'm Using Alamofire 4.5 with Swift 3.1.

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint inside the `Alamofire` closure? The requests are asynchronous so if you're just stepping over the code it might appear not to be called.

Comment: Also, your `url` is blank, is that for the purpose of this example?

Comment: @Ollie the url is blank for the purpose :) And yeah I have added a bunch of breakpoints. After the Request is called the debugger skips right to the end.

Comment: If your URL is blank then how can Alamofire will give you response?

Comment: @devangbhatt the blank url is only for the scenario description. In the "working" example the Url is filled

Comment: URLEncoding.default replace to URLEncoding.httpbody, try this

Answer (score 1):

Please use different types of data request handling block and check again.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default)

.responseJSON { response in
    print("JSON Response")
}
.responseData { response in
    print("Data Response")              
}
.responseString { response in
    print("String Response")
}
.responsePropertyList { response in
    print("PropertyList Response")
}
```